# How to use Segment's Visual Tagger with a React app in localhost

Tags: reactjs, https, localhost, segment, event-tracking

I am adding Segment to a React app made with Create React App to track the users' events. I tried to use the Visual Tagger feature but when I add my development URL `http://localhost:3000` the page loads but then I get this error:

```
Your site is not on https
Visual Tagger cannot be used on sites that do not use https. Please change your url in Source Settings to proceed
```

[image]

I have been searching around the docs and web without success if there is a way to use this feature in a local development environment. Someone knows a way to solve this, get through it, or if it is just not possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I set up https for localhost:

- follow install instructions at: https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert
- add the following line to your package.json scripts section:

```
"mkcert": "mkcert localhost && cat ./localhost-key.pem ./localhost.pem > ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl/server.pem"
```

- for the start script, add `HTTPS=true`, for example:

```
"start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
```

- run the following command now, and then occasionally whenever the certificate expires:

```
npm run mkcert
```

- Now when you run `npm start`, your browser should open https://localhost:3000

I hope that helps.

Comment: this doesn't work for me unfortunately - there's a problem with chrome marking the certificate as invalid even though it expires in over 3 years